# unable to create multiple marker using the data from my query

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

Why when I try querying the data I only get one marker on my google map?

What should be the best way? Please help just newbie in coding.

```
<?php
$query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT imdb.STATION,imdb.PEIS,imdb.PGA,imdb.PGV, station.LAT, station.LON  FROM imdb, station WHERE imdb.MAC = station.MAC and  YYYYMMDD between '$from' and '$to'and HHMMSS between '$from1' and '$to1';");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                                $station = $row['STATION'];
                                $pei = $row['PEIS'];
                                $pga= $row['PGA'];
                                $pgv= $row['PGV'];
                                $lat = $row['LAT'];
                                $lon = $row['LON'];}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

      function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $lon; ?>};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {zoom: 4,center: myLatLng});

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBM2-ikIyV0IMgQ31Rtpn_XBAMTm9wKup4&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: You're overriding the variables you've defined inside the `while` loop. Define them before initiating the loop and use an array instead. What I do is, I encode them into JSON and decode them in JavaScript using `JSON.parse`, iterate the loop, and put the markers.

Comment: Hi sir can you give me some example of it im new in programming greatly appreciate it

Comment: Please check the answer I posted and mark it as answer it if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP asked, I'm providing a working example that can plugged into the code appropriately to make it work:

```
<?php
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $result[]['lat'] = $row['LAT'];
    $result[]['lon'] = $row['LON'];
}
?>
```

Use the following script to initialize and create the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var locationsJSON = '<?php echo json_encode($result) ?>';
    var locations = JSON.parse(locationsJSON);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        console.log(locations[i]);
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: im able to see some of the data  from the query but the map didnt load you can see the full code and check whats needed to correct it

Comment: Put the script inside `initMap` as it's supposed to be called.

Comment: sir i already put the script inside the initMap function then i put this
 <body onload ="initMap()"> but still the map is not loading.thank you in adnvance

Comment: I can't do much with 'not showing'. Did you check the browser console? Are there any errors? Was the map working before?

Comment: yes the map before the changes is working fine able to get even 1 marker on the map but when i change the map is not working no error just the map not working

Comment: Create another API key for the maps and put the Google Maps script tag on the top of the page.

Comment: hi sir basit can you check the one that i post thank you so much your helping alot

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi can you check on this code is this correct and i place the google map script at the top before the body part of the page

<script type="text/javascript">

      function initMap() {
var locationsJSON = '<?php echo json_encode($result) ?>';
var locations = JSON.parse(locationsJSON);

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    console.log(locations[i]);
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });
  }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check why i keep on getting this error

Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

```
$the_array  = array();               
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

              $station = $row['STATION'];
              $pei = $row['PEIS'];
              $pga= $row['PGA'];
              $pgv= $row['PGV'];
              //$array_lat_lon[] = $lat = $row['LAT'];
              //$array_lat_lon[] = $lon = $row['LON'];
              $the_array[] = array($row['LAT'] . "," . $row['LON']) ;      
              //$timestamp = strtotime()

              echo '<tr><td>'.$station.'</td><td>'.$pei.'</td><td>'.$pga.'</td><td>'.$pgv.'</td></tr>';
                          }
              //echo $lat.'<br>';
              //echo $lon.'<br>';
              //echo json_encode($the_array);

              $location_array = json_decode('$the_array');
              $location_array = array_map('json_decode', $location_array[$the_array]);
              echo $location_array;
                          }
                          }
                  ?>
```